# All pages in a jquery mobile / phonegap build showing

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I am working on a PhoneGap app using jQuery. When I test the app on the desktop all Navigation links work great and the `data-role="page"` are separating and displaying / not displaying perfectly fine.

however when I build it using PhoneGap Builder, when I run the app ALL the pages display as part of the first page and the entire thing is scrollable.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
// script to allow swipeleft/right through nav pages
// flip effect transition required

</script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="navPage1">

    <div data-role="content"><a href="#facebookFeed"><img id="fb_image" style="margin-left: .5em; margin-right: 0em; margin-bottom: 0em; margin-top: .5em; width: 288px; height: 320px;" src="assets/images/fb_image.png" alt="mctn_facebook"></img></a>
      <a href="#twitterFeed"><img id="twt_image" style="margin-left: .5em; margin-right: .25em; height: 130px; width: 138px;" src="assets/images/twt_image.png" alt="mctn_twitter" ></img></a>
      <a href="#youtubeFeed"><img id="yt_image" style="margin-right: .5em; height: 130px; width: 138px;" src="assets/images/yt_image.png" alt="mctn_youtube"></img></a>    </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="navPage2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="navPage3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Three</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the question --

I ended up placing the .js files in the app folder itself instead of calling them remotely.

worked perfectly right away.

Comment: This is most likely because you weren't whitelisting jquery.com [Whitelist Info](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide)